# Why is the options endpoint returning option values I did not create?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm working on a site for a client. I'm attempting to use the API to create *products/variants* for the client's store. To start off, I am creating the "base" products using the products/catalog endpoint. This works just fine, I can view the base product in the BigCommerce Control Panel and on the storefront.

The issue comes in when I want to create the variants for the base products. I use the *catalog/products/{product_id}/options* endpoint to send in the options I would like the variant to have. As a test, I used Postman to send a request to create some test color options for one of my products (RED, BLUE and GREEN). The request is processed, but the response is very odd. The response indicates that my color options were created, but for some reason BigCommerce also mixed in some size options as well. To make matters worse, when I try to view my product in the Control Panel the page does not load. Other products continue to load, but the product that I just created the variants for doesn't.

Here's a screenshot of the request (as you can see, I only requested for some colors to be created)
[image: Request]

And here's the response (notice that the response includes size options I did not ask to be created)

[image: Response]

Here's a screenshot of the product page that refuses to load after the variants are created

[image: Product Page]

Thanks for any help anyone can give us.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely out of the ordinary, and I would recommend to reach out to the [BigCommerce technical support team here](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/#contact) for further troubleshooting. I wasn't able to reproduce the same behavior following those steps, so if there's anything I might have missed feel free to reach back out!